# ms sql powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, management-studio-express

I want to execute a powershell script within microsoft management studio.
But I get an error. Look below for more details:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell '%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -command "C:\tmp_es\test.ps1"'

C:\tmp_es\test.ps1 : The term 'C:\tmp_es\test.ps1' is not recognized as the 
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
```

Comment: It's probably because the SQL process doesn't have access to `C:\tmp_es` Try changing the permission on `tmp_es` to read all users.

Comment: I think you are right. But now I must know what the name is of the sql management studio server. Do you maybe know?

Comment: Are you running Sql Server on the same machine as Management Studio, or on a remote server?

Comment: Yeah. It is running on the same machine. So what can I do ?

Comment: It was indeed the wrong path. Now I've inserted the good path and it is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the `-Command` to `-File`

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell '%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -File "C:\tmp_es\test.ps1"'
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I think indeed it has no permission to that folder sql management studio.